# base module not found in colab

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing my project. It comes with an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9252d2779950> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 from base import Regressor, RegressorBuilder
     13 
     14 from util import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

How could I resolve this?

I am expecting error free code.

Comment: What is `base`?